# Parsing an html table with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-table, html-parsing

I am trying to take the data of a given day from this timetable: [click here](http://timetable.leeds.ac.uk/teaching/current/reporting/Individual;?objectclass=student+set&idtype=id&identifier=846163&periods=1-21&days=1-7&template=SWSCUST+Student+Set+Individual+Links+semester&weeks=14)

I have been able to use Beautiful Soup to add an entire row for any given day (in this case, monday or 'Mon') to a list using this code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

day ='Mon'

with open('timetable.txt', 'rt') as input_file:
  html = input_file.read()
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
  #finds correct day tag
  starttag = soup.find(text=day).parent.parent
  print starttag
  nexttag = starttag
  row=[]
  x = 0
  #puts all td tags for that day in a list
  while x < 18:
    nexttag = nexttag.nextSibling.nextSibling
    row.append(nexttag)
    x += 1
print row
```

as you can see, the command returns a list of TD tags, which make up the 'mon' row in the timetable.

My problem is, I don't know how to further parse or search the returned list to find the relevant info (COMP1740 etc.).

If I can find out how to search each element in the list for the module codes, I can then concatenate them alongside another list of timings, giving the timetable for a single day.

All help is welcome! (including completely different approaches)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find information like the course numbers using Regular Expressions, i.e., pattern matching.

I don't know your experience with them, but Python includes a 're' module.  Looking at the pattern of "The four letters C-O-M-P followed by one or more digits."  gives a RegEx of `COMP\d+` where `\d` is one digit and the following `+` says to look for as many as possible (in this case, 4).

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

day ='Mon'
codePat = re.compile(r'COMP\d+')

with open('timetable.txt', 'rt') as input_file:
  html = input_file.read()
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
  #finds correct day tag
  starttag = soup.find(text=day).parent.parent
#  print starttag
  nexttag = starttag
  row=[]
  x = 0
  #puts all td tags for that day in a list
  while x < 18:
    nexttag = nexttag.nextSibling.nextSibling
    found = codePat.search(repr(nexttag))
    if found:
      row.append(found.group(0))
    x += 1
print row
```

This gives me the output,

```
['COMP1940', 'COMP1550', 'COMP1740']
```

Like I said, I don't know where your knowledge of Regular Expressions is, so if you can describe the patterns I can try to write them.  [Here's a good resource](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) if you decide to do it on your own.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Turns out only MY module codes start with 'COMP' so I just changed the search pattern to 'rowspan="1"' because that was the only other thing in the code which gives away that there a module at that point in the table. I'll post the new code as an answer.

Comment: @Ben, about your new answer: When you get past the last sibling, nexttag will be None, so you can say ```if not nexttag: break```.  It's cleaner than a try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

#day input
day ='Thu'
#searches for a module (where html has rowspan="1")
module = re.compile(r'rowspan=\"1\"')
#lengths of module search (depending on html colspan attribute)
#1.5 hour
perlen15 = re.compile(r'colspan=\"3\"')
#2 hour
perlen2 = re.compile(r'colspan=\"4\"')
#2.5 hour etc.
perlen25 = re.compile(r'colspan=\"5\"')
perlen3 = re.compile(r'colspan=\"6\"')
perlen35 = re.compile(r'colspan=\"7\"')
perlen4 = re.compile(r'colspan=\"8\"')
#times correspond to first row of timetable.
times = ['8:00', '8:30', '9:00', '9:30', '10:00', '10:30', '11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30', '13:00', '13:30', '14:00', '14:30', '15:00', '15:30']

#opens full timetable html
with open('timetable.txt', 'rt') as input_file:
  html = input_file.read()
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
  #finds correct day tag
  starttag = soup.find(text=day).parent.parent
  nexttag = starttag
  row=[]
  #movement of cursor iterating over times list
  curmv = 0
  #puts following td tags for that day in a list
  for time in times:
    nexttag = nexttag.nextSibling.nextSibling
    #detect if a module is found
    found = module.search(repr(nexttag))
    #detect length of that module
    hour15 = perlen15.search(repr(nexttag))
    hour2 = perlen2.search(repr(nexttag))
    hour25 = perlen25.search(repr(nexttag))
    hour3 = perlen3.search(repr(nexttag))
    hour35 = perlen35.search(repr(nexttag))
    hour4 = perlen4.search(repr(nexttag))
    if found: 
      row.append(times[curmv])
      row.append(nexttag)
      if hour15:
        curmv += 3
      elif hour2:
        curmv += 4
      elif hour25:
        curmv += 5
      elif hour3:
        curmv += 6
      elif hour35:
        curmv += 7
      elif hour4:
        curmv += 8
      else:
        curmv += 2
    else:
      curmv += 1
#write day to html file
with open('output.html', 'wt') as output_file:
  for e in row:
    output_file.write(str(e))
```

as you can see, the code can differentiate between one hour and 2 hour long lectures as well as 1.5, 2.5 hour longs ones etc.

my only problem now is line 32, I need a better way to tell the code to stop moving horizontally across the table aka: knowing when to stop the for loop (in the previous code I had `while x < 18:` which only worked for monday because there were 18 td tags in the row. How can I get the loop to stop when it hits the parent `</tr>` tag?

thanks!

EDIT: I'm going to try using a try and except block to catch the error I get if I set the 'times' set all the way up to 18:00.

EDIT2: IT WORKED! :D